# how do i delete array property from an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I want to delete the property `period_to` and `period_from` but if i use delete.period_to or `delete.period_to[0]` it does not delete.

```
function someData(data)
{
    var formkey = [];
    var formval = [];
    var ch = data;
    var clen = ch.length;
    for(var i =0; i < clen; i++){
        formkey.push(ch[i].name);
        formval.push(ch[i].value);
    }
    var result = {};
    formkey.forEach((key, i) => result[key] = formval[i]);

    delete result.table;
    delete result.redirect_to;
    delete result.dbres;
    delete result.period_to;
    delete result.period_from;
    //console.log(result);
    //
    return result;
}
```

-- chrome console

```
{name: "qwerty", client_id: "1", user_id: "1", period_from[2]: "11", period_from[1]: "01", …}
client_id: "1"
name: "qwerty"
period_from[0]: "11"
period_from[1]: "01"
period_from[2]: "11"
period_to[0]: "111"
period_to[1]: "09"
period_to[2]: "11"
user_id: "1"
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: sorry this is my code `delete result.period_to;`

Comment: I added answer with multiple scenarios. Hope it will work as per in the understanding as per your expectation.

Answer (score 1):

**Few observations :**

- If your obj is like as per the `-- chrome console` section in `OP`. Then you should delete the object properties with exact name.

  **DEMO**

```js
var obj = {
  "client_id": "1",
  "name": "qwerty",
  "period_from[0]": "11",
  "period_from[1]": "01",
  "period_from[2]": "11",
  "period_to[0]": "111",
  "period_to[1]": "09",
  "period_to[2]": "11",
  "user_id": "1"
};

delete obj["period_to[0]"];
delete obj["period_from[0]"];

console.log(obj);
```

- If your object is like this :

  ```
   var obj = {
    "client_id": "1",
    "name": "qwerty",
    "period_from": ["11","01","11"],
    "period_to[0]": ["111","09","11"],
    "user_id": "1"
  };
  ```

  Then try below code **:**

```js
var obj = {
  "client_id": "1",
  "name": "qwerty",
  "period_from": ["11","01","11"],
  "period_to": ["111","09","11"],
  "user_id": "1"
};

delete obj.period_to;
delete obj.period_from;

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete is an operator and not a function. Remove the period and replace with space.

`delete data.period_to`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to delete `period_from[2]`, for example, you're going to have to put quotes around the key name as it's currently not valid. You can then use bracket notation to delete the property.

```js
const obj = {
  name: "qwerty",
  client_id: "1",
  user_id: "1",
  "period_from[2]": "11",
  "period_from[1]": "01"
}

delete obj['period_from[2]'];
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer correct to help future viewers of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can pare down the first part of that to a single reduce function, should make it a lot more readable and easy to troubleshoot.

Also instead of trying to do a bunch of deletes afterward, you can test the properties upfront and only add the ones you want.

```js
var propRgx = /^(table|redirect_to|dbres|period_to|period_from)/

function allowProperty(prop){
  return !propRgx.test(prop) //if the property matches any of those, return false
}

function someData(data)
    {
        //All of the assignment can be replaced with this reduce, and instead of deleting afterward, you can test the properties inside of here:
        var result = data.reduce(function(obj, t){
          if(allowProperty(t.name)) obj[t.name] = t.value
          return obj
        }, {})
        
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `rest` and `destructuring`:

```js
var obj = {name: "1", client_id: "1", user_id: "1", period_from: [], period_to: []};

var period_to, period_from;

({period_to, period_from, ...obj} = obj);

console.log(obj);
```